# Can image be link as $next in pagination?

Tags: javascript, php, pagination

I have problem with image which should act like next button in pagination. On this page numbers, next and previus buttons are working perfectly.

I want be able to click on image "`Naprijed.png`" and it should redirect me to "`smartphone?page=2`". When page is "`smartphone?page=2`", click on image "Naprijed.png" should redirect me to "`smartphone?page=3`" etc.

Is that even possible on the way I want or not?

```
    <html>
            <body>
                <div id="container">
                    <?php
                    // 5. record shown amount
                    $per_page = 10;
                    // 7. current page
                    if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
                        $page = 1;
                    } else {
                        $page = $_GET['page'];
                    }

                    // 4. mysql start possition
                    if ($page <= 1) {
                        $start = 0;
                    } else {
                        $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
                    }

                    $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='smartphone' ORDER BY id ASC ";

                    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $query));

                    $num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $per_page);
                    ?>

                    <div id="natrag">   
                        <img src="Okviri/Natrag.png" width="70" height="70" alt="Natrag" onclick="goBack()" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">

                        <script>
                            function goBack() {
                                window.history.back();
                            }
                        </script>

                        <?php echo '<a class="two" href=index><img src="Okviri/home.png" width="70px" height="70px" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;"></a>'; ?>

                        <img src="Okviri/Naprijed.png" width="70" height="70" alt="Naprijed" onclick="goForward()" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">

                        <script>
                            function goForward() {
                                window.location.href = "smartphone?page=$next";
                            }
                        </script>
                    </div>

                    <div id="pagination">
                        <?php

                        $prev = $page - 1;
                        $next = $page + 1;

                        $order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : '';

                        // prev
                        if ($prev > 0) {
                            echo "<a style='text-decoration:none; font-size:30px; color: #099BCD;' href='?page=$prev&order=$order'><b><</b></a> ";
                        }
                        //numbers
                        $number = 1;
                        for ($number; $number <= $num_pages; $number +=1) {
                            if ($page == $number) {
                                echo " <b style='font-size:30px; color: #099BCD;'> $number </b> ";
                            } else {
                                echo " <a style='text-decoration:none; font-size:30px; color: #099BCD;' href='?page=$number&order=$order'>$number</a> ";
                            }
                        }

                        // next
                        if ($page < ceil($num_rows / $per_page)) {
                            echo " <a  style='text-decoration:none; font-size:30px; color: #099BCD;'  href='?page=$next&order=$order'><b>></b></a> ";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>

                    <div id="gumb"> 
                        <div id="usporedivanje">
                            <input type='submit' form='Forma' name='usporedi' disabled='disabled' id='usporedi' value='Usporedi' onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" />

                            <div id='sortiranje'>
                                <select id='filter' style="font-size:20px; height:50px; border: 5px solid #099CDB; border-radius: 10px; border-color: #099bcd;" name="filter" onchange="window.location.href = 'smartphone?order=' + this.value">
                                    <option>Poredaj po: </option>
                                    <option value="naziv">Naziv</option>
                                    <option value="cijenaasc">Cijena Manja-Veća</option>
                                    <option value="cijenadesc">Cijena Veća-Manja</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br/>
                        <form id="Forma" method='post'>
                            <?php

                            $order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : '';
                            if ($order) {
                                switch ($order) {
                                    case 'cijenaasc':
                                        $order = 'cijena';
                                        $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='smartphone' ORDER BY CAST(cijena AS DECIMAL(8,2)) ASC ";
                                        break;

                                    case 'naziv':
                                        $order = 'naziv';
                                        $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='smartphone' ORDER BY naziv ASC ";
                                        break;

                                    case 'cijenadesc':
                                        $order = 'cijena';
                                        $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='smartphone' ORDER BY CAST(cijena AS DECIMAL(8,2)) DESC ";
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                            $query .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";
                            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                                $id = $row ['id'];

                                print
                                        "<div id='proizvod'></br><a style='text-decoration:none; color:black; font-size:20px;' class='two' href='proizvod.php?id=$id' ><b>" . $row["naziv"] . "</b>" .
                                        "<p><img src=" . $row["slika"] . " width='200px' height='200px' style='border-radius: 15px;'></p>" .
                                        "<p style='font-size:20px'><b> Cijena za gotovinu: " . $row["cijena"] . " KN </b></p>" .
                                        "<pre id='pre1'>" . $row["opis"] . "</pre>" .
                                        "</a></div>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php include "footer.php"; ?>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, in your `goForward` function, you have the following code:

```
window.location.href = "smartphone?page=$next";
```

This doesn't work. You can put `$next` in PHP strings just fine, but outside PHP tags it will just be ignored. You can simply solve this by putting it in PHP tags:

```
window.location.href = "smartphone?page=<?php echo $next;?>";
```

Edit: also, you are defining the $next variable after this code. So you need to move that up.

Comment: This is not working, even when I define $next variable.

Comment: @Smjak in what way doesn't it work? You can't click the button, or it takes you to the wrong page?

Comment: I can click button, but nothing happens. URL changes to "smartphone?page=<?php echo $next;?>" but it doesn't pull data from database. I think that variable $next is problem, but don't know why.